# how do you determine the connection pool size of a e.g nodejs app.. based on the connection limit?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, instance, connection-pooling

Both apps are hosted in aws beanstalk and they are the same code base

- Divide connection limit across apps e.g if i have two instances then its 50/50 both instances

OR

- Set the Connection limit equal to the connection pool.

I have an API accessed by two kinds of users over a monolithic architecture, and I expect a +10k unique users. The users are event organizers and participants. I'm using a pooling mechanism of each nodejs instances.

My question is: how should I distribute the connection pool based on my database, having a limit of say 500 connection_limi. Or do I adjust my nodejs replica to the limit of my database or just set all replica to 500 pool connectionn?

Comment: Are you talking about `max_connections`? Are the applications sharing the same database and user (which would be a bad idea)?

Comment: nope 1 api is sharing a database

Comment: Sharing with whom?

Comment: i have an API accessed by two kinds of users over a monolithic architecture  i expect a +10k unique users the users are event organizers and participant i'm using a pooling mechanism of each nodejs instances my question is how should i distribute the connection pool based on my database having a limit of say 500 connection_limi. or do i adjust my nodejs replica to the limit of my database or just set all replica to 500 pool connection

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have several application server instances connecting to a single database.

Then you should install pgBouncer on the database server, because connection pooling on the application server alone would not be effective. You should set the pool size to something very small like 20 - 50, depending on the number of cores on the database and the number of concurrent I/O requests the database storage can handle. It does not really matter how many connections to pgBouncer you allow.

Make sure your database transactions are short and use transaction pooling mode, and you will be able to handle a big workload.

Comment: i don't think i can install pgbouncer i'm using RDS for my database i guess my options maybe is read-replica and multi az.. but thank you for answering